# IIS8 The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions

Tags: asp.net, dll, loadlibrary, iis-8

Windows Server 2012 64 bit
IIS8
ASP.NET Framework 4

Trying to run an unmanaged DLL from my aspx page

Executing the DLL Function call gives:

The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions. To debug this process, the Just-In-Time debugger must be run as an Administrator. Would you like to debug this process?

There is no debugger that I know of on the web server, trying to launch it gives errors.

1. Why is my call to my DLL crashing my aspnet worker process?
2. How can I tell IIS8 there is no debugger?

I have googled this extensively, and all the help seems to be about Visual Studio, not IIS.  There is no Visual Studio on the web sever.

Here is the offending code.

```
private string regname = "";
private string fingerprint = "";
private string unlockingcode = "";

/// <summary>
/// called from page_load
/// </summary>
private void CreateUnlockingCode()
{
    UInt32 lfp;
    string sfp = fingerprint.Remove(4, 1);
    lfp = Convert.ToUInt32(sfp, 16);

    string bindir = Server.MapPath(@"~/bin/CodeGen64.dll");  //full path to the DLL "P:\\AFI2013\\bin\\CodeGen64.dll"               

    IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(bindir);  //attempt to load the library
    try
    {
        IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "CreateCode2A");
        CreateCode2 createCode2 = (CreateCode2)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
            pAddressOfFunctionToCall,
            typeof(CreateCode2));

        //THIS LINE CRASHES THE ASPNET WORKER PROCESS
        unlockingcode = createCode2(1, regname, encrypt_template, lfp, (UInt16)0, (UInt16)0, (UInt16)0, (UInt16)0, (UInt16)0);
    }
    finally
    {
        bool result = NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(pDll);
    }
}
```

And here is the Error from the Event Viewer.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          7/10/2013 11:34:30 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      owl.INT.local
Description:
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50108835
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16579, time stamp: 0x51637f77
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ebd59
Faulting process id: 0x2608
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce7d9c1d409343
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 5b36e881-e98f-11e2-9406-000c2908dae4
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-07-10T18:34:30.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>54586</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>owl.INT.local</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>8.0.9200.16384</Data>
    <Data>50108835</Data>
    <Data>ntdll.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.2.9200.16579</Data>
    <Data>51637f77</Data>
    <Data>c0000374</Data>
    <Data>00000000000ebd59</Data>
    <Data>2608</Data>
    <Data>01ce7d9c1d409343</Data>
    <Data>c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll</Data>
    <Data>5b36e881-e98f-11e2-9406-000c2908dae4</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Check in Control Panel (Programs and Features) if "Webcompanion" by Lavasoft is installed on your machine?